# Plank Workout Ruotine?

Tags: exercise, workout-routines, strength, muscle, strength-training

Ok guys I'm working on tightening my core and getting a six pack back.

Currently I max out at 60 seconds for a single plank

I was wondering if anyone could help me set up a plank workout routine.

Like how many planks I should do in a set, how long should I hold the planks for, and how many sets I should do a day?

I plan to do the work out 3 days a week.

Answer (score 1):

Doing planks is good, you can increase the difficulty by putting weight on your back (10kg plate should do the trick). I usually do 3 sets of weighted plants (30sec-1min).

You should also do movements:

- Captains Chair
- Hanging leg raise/toes-to-bar
- Windscreen wipers
- Crunches
- Oblique-twists

With respect to getting a 6-pack to show: Abs are made in the gym but are revealed in the kitchen. Your body-fat percentage should be low to show abs.

Comment: I used to be fit but that was years ago, I appreciate your input. I usually workout at home if I can't go to the gym.  I will try all of those. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I have a plank routine in my exercise days - about every other day. Basically, it's ten minutes where I do either 1 minute plank/1 minute rest or 30 sec plank/30 sec rest until the 10 minutes are up. I do the planks on my elbows.

I don't know if that seems to easy/hard for you, but you could vary the durations as needed. (I recently moved up 35 sec plank/25 rest.)

However you time your sets I suggest you pay attention to *how* you do the work. I don't just hold the position, I squeeze my ads tightly as much as I can. A bit of glute and quads tighten too. I think this is what trainers call posterior pelvic tilt. The point is to maximize the work of the muscles not simply hold a position. You want to avoid a limp, saggy plank. 'Walking' on your hands to get in and out of the plank position is another way to keep up the work on your core when doing planks.

Comment: I too tighten it as much as I can I can feel it by the time I'm almost done how much tighter it feels. Lets me know I'm doing it right. And that doesn't sound bad either.

Comment: @TColeT sounds like you're on track. The other obvious point that comes up is diet.